# working out First event and last event

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, events

I am working on some event data with date time. there is an ID for each event **gsm_id** column. For each event, there is a starting date and time **matchdatetime** column. there will be multiple events occuring and represented by the column **eventdatetime** column. There is also a column which record **PreviousEventTime**column. How can i do create a new column to record the following: 1) first event for each "gsm_ID where **matchdatetime** column and **PreviousEventTime** column are the same 2) the last event for each **gsm_id** where "eventdatetime" is the latest.

```
    gsm_id   eventdatetime  matchdatetime   PreviousEventTime
    2462794 8/11/2017 18:46 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 18:45
    2462794 8/11/2017 18:49 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 18:46
    2462794 8/11/2017 19:13 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 18:49
    2462794 8/11/2017 19:31 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 19:13
    2462794 8/11/2017 19:40 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 19:31
    2462794 8/11/2017 20:07 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 19:40
    2462794 8/11/2017 20:09 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 20:07
    2462796 8/12/2017 14:23 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:00
    2462796 8/12/2017 14:38 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:23
    2462796 8/12/2017 14:42 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:38
    2462796 8/12/2017 15:08 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:42
    2462796 8/12/2017 15:27 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 15:08
    2462795 8/12/2017 17:39 8/12/2017 16:30 8/12/2017 16:30
    2462795 8/12/2017 17:44 8/12/2017 16:30 8/12/2017 17:39
```

Can any one advise how to work out?
If you wish to load the file, please download the file below:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SWuxm2PtLSphH6lvivPioTlfLe2JhGH1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
In [203]: s1 = df[df['PreviousEventTime'] == df['matchdatetime']].groupby('gsm_id')['eventdatetime'].first()

In [204]: s1
Out[204]: 
gsm_id
2462794   2017-08-11 18:46:00
2462795   2017-08-12 17:39:00
2462796   2017-08-12 14:23:00
Name: eventdatetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [205]: s2 = df.groupby('gsm_id')['eventdatetime'].last()

In [206]: s2
Out[206]: 
gsm_id
2462794   2017-08-11 20:09:00
2462795   2017-08-12 17:44:00
2462796   2017-08-12 15:27:00
Name: eventdatetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then finally:

```
df.set_index('gsm_id').assign(myfirst=s1, mylast=s2).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks Liliscent, It works.
I want to place both first event and last event in a new column and replace the datestime with string "first_event" for first event and "last event" for last event. Would you mind to advise?

Comment: Change the last line to `df.set_index('gsm_id').assign(**{"first_event":s1,  "last event":s2}).reset_index()`. And please don't forget upvote answers that are helpful.

Comment: Hi Liliscent,
I am trying to create two new columns 
`df['First-Event'] =s1`
`dr ['Last_Event'] = s2`
It showed me NaT in both new columns.
Can you please advise what went wrong
Thanks

Comment: @Zephyr Please *strictly* follow the steps in the answer, it was tested without any problem. You probably forgot `set_index()` or something.

Comment: I did.. set the index too.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize pandas groupby objects for both questions.

#### Question 1)

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Data_test.csv')
```

First find the indices where matchdatetime and PreviousEventTime is equal and then group by "gsm_id". Finally aggregate by the "first" function:

```
first_equal_dates = df[df['PreviousEventTime'] == df['matchdatetime']].groupby('gsm_id')['eventdatetime'].first()
```

You can then merge/join this on the original dataframe.

#### Question 2)

Again just groupby "gsm_id", but use the "last" function instead:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('Data_test.csv')
last_event_dates = data.groupby('gsm_id').agg({'eventdatetime': 'last'})
```

Again just merge/join this on the original dataframe if you want it as a column in the dataframe.

You can also just assign the results in an one-liner:

```
data.set_index('gsm_id').assign(question_1=first_equal_dates, mylast=last_event_dates).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks mfavs.
It works. I want to place both first event and last event in a new column and replace the datestime with string "first_event" for first event and "last event" for last event. Would you mind to advise?